# Google Sheets Apps Script for sorting but keeping blanks and "our warranty" in alphebetical order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't seem to find a script that will automatically sort the sheet based on values in column V. I have a script to auto-sort in reverse alphabetically so that the cells that contain "Factory warranty" are at the bottom of the data range BUT it also moves blanks to the bottom, which I don't want. I am looking to have "Our Warranty" containing cells and the blank cells (both in column V) to be alphabetical based on the last name BUT if column V contains "Factory warranty" to go to the bottom of the group (not to the bottom of the entire sheet) also alphabetically on the last name. Here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZsaZYd-IUT7OjMOgTEki6lTgVzS72Tx1QihfpSjGhWY/edit?usp=sharing is the sample sheet and below is the script.

```
function AutoSortOnEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Service")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:V200");
  range.sort(22);
  range.sort({column: 22, ascending: false});
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Access denied on your sheet

Comment: Still cant make a copy / or see the script